# Find eigen energies of time-independent Schrödinger equation

Tags: equation-solving, physics, parametric-functions

I'm trying to get the eigenvalues of a one dimensional time-independent Schrödinger equation,

$-\frac{h^2}{2m_0}\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}+U(x)~\psi=Ei~\psi$

where U(x) is some potential and Ei is the eigen energy. I'm trying to find the Ei if given a potential U(x).

For example, if U(x) is the harmonic potential

$U(x)=\frac{1}{2}m_0\omega^2x^2$

then the solution for Ei would be

$Ei=(n+\frac{1}{2})\hbar\omega$.

---

Here is my try to solve a harmonic potential:

There is a new function introduced in version 9 called [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html) which can be used to solve parametric differential equations. In its [advertisement](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/parametric-differential-equations/eigenproblems.html), there is a demonstration of solving a similar eigenproblem of the finite potential well. There the energy is treated as a parameter, and then the Schrödinger is solved as a parameter of the energy. Then we select only the energies that make the wave function vanish at large distance, which is required by physics. Those selected energies are the eigen energy of the system. Here I use the same way.

```
\[HBar] = e = m0 = 1.; ω = 1;
U[x_] := 1/2 m0 ω^2 x^2
```

The potential is symmetric, so that the wave function must be odd or even function.

First if the wave function is odd, then it must goes through zero.

```
pfun1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{-(\[HBar]^2/(2 m0)) ψ''[x] + 
     U[x] ψ[x] == Ei ψ[x], ψ[0.] == 0., ψ[1.] == 
    1.}, ψ, {x, -4, 4}, {Ei}]
```

These are the solutions

```
Show[Plot[U[x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Green]]
 , Plot[Evaluate@Table[Re[pfun1[Ei][x]], {Ei, 0., 5., 0.5}], {x, -4, 
   4}], PlotRange -> {All, {-6, 10}}]
```

[image]

The wave function value at -4 as a function of parameter Ei

```
Plot[pfun1[Ei][-4], {Ei, 0, 5}, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

We can select the energies which make the wave function goes to zero, those are the eigen energies. (Note that previously this just said val instead of val1, which gave an error down the road.)

```
val1 = Map[
  FindRoot[pfun1[Ei][-4], {Ei, #}] &, {1, 2, 3}]
(*{{Ei -> 1.50001}, {Ei -> 1.50001}, {Ei -> 3.50169}}*)
```

Similarly, if the wave function is even, then the first derivative should be 0 at 0.

```
pfun2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{-(\[HBar]^2/(2 m0)) ψ''[x] + 
     U[x] ψ[x] == Ei ψ[x], ψ'[0.] == 0., ψ[1.] == 
    1.}, ψ, {x, -4, 4}, {Ei}]
Show[Plot[U[x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Green]]
 , Plot[Evaluate@Table[Re[pfun2[Ei][x]], {Ei, 0., 5., 0.5}], {x, -4, 
   4}], PlotRange -> {All, {-6, 10}}]
Plot[pfun2[Ei][-4], {Ei, 0, 5}, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]
[image]

The eigen energies can be selected in the same way

```
val2 = Map[FindRoot[pfun2[Ei][-4], {Ei, #}] &, {1, 2, 3}]
(*{{Ei -> 0.5}, {Ei -> 2.5002}, {Ei -> 2.5002}}*)
```

So finally the eigen energyies are

```
eigenEv = val1 /. Rule[_, x_] -> x // Flatten;
eigenOd = val2 /. Rule[_, x_] -> x // Flatten;
Sort[Join[eigenEv, eigenOd]]
(*{0.5, 1.50001, 1.50001, 2.5002, 2.5002, 3.50169}*)
```

eigen functions are

```
Show[Plot[U[x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Green]]
 , Plot[Evaluate@{Table[Re[pfun1[Ei][x]], {Ei, eigenEv}], 
    Table[Re[pfun2[Ei][x]], {Ei, eigenOd}]}, {x, -4, 4}], 
 PlotRange -> {All, {-3, 3}}]
```

[image]

which basically agree with the analytical results.

---

**Questions**:

1. Are there other ways to find the eigen energies which are more efficient and accurate than the parameter methods? For example, in this case we can see that the fourth eigen energy should be exactly 3.5 but it gave 3.50169 which is quite a large error. Also in my real system, I'm interested in calculating up to the hundredth eigen energies, this method seems too slow to do that.
2. If the potential U(x) is not symmetric, how do I set the initial or value? For example, in the harmonic potential case, we set `ψ'[0]=0, ψ[1]=1` in the even case and `ψ[0]=0, ψ[1]=1` in the odd case, in a more general potential, how do I set the initial or boundary value?

Comment: From my understanding of quantum mechanics I don't believe you need to specify two different boundary conditions. In fact, in the example you linked to, for the particle in a finite square well problem, only I set of boundary conditions were supplied. To set the boundary conditions for any potential, you'll have to understand the physics of the problem, there's no general rule of thumb for that.

Comment: @xslittlegrass This is a very good post and is helping me a lot.  I have a question for you about your code.  When you find the eigenvalues for the case of odd wave functions you get 1.5 and 3.5 as the Ei.  How do you tell your code to only give you two eigenvalues, what if you wanted more than 2 at this step?

Comment: @Jeff I guess you can just change the `FindRoot` line in the code and let it return more roots.

Comment: @xslittlegrass Thanks for the reply!  Do you mean something like

val = Map[
  FindRoot[pfun1[Ei][-4], {Ei, #}] &, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}] 
which will find 5 roots, rather than 3 which is what you had found? (2 being identical)

Comment: @Jeff Yes, I think so :)

Comment: @xslittlegrass thanks for your time.

Comment: @xslittlegrass Sorry this may seem like an obvious question, but how would you do this problem had the potential NOT been even?  What if it is odd? Thank you

Comment: @Jeff I guess you need a even potential to have bound states.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You asked for alternative approaches to what you did, so here is one:

A completely different approach to the one-dimensional time-independent Schrödinger equation would be to use **matrix techniques**. The idea is to eliminate the need for `NDSolve` entirely. For bound-state problems, you can do this by choosing a basis satisfying the condition of vanishing wave function at infinity and expanding all quantities in that basis.

A particularly nice way of doing this has been pointed out in:

> H. J. Korsch and M Glück, "Computing quantum eigenvalues made easy"
>   Eur. J. Phys. 23 (2002) 413-426.

It uses the harmonic-oscillator basis, but also introduces the relation between position and momentum operators on one hand, and the harmonic-oscillator operators on the other hand. This makes it very useful as a teaching method.

**I implemented that approach here, with some refinements to satisfy given tolerances and make plots:**

---

The potential energy $U(x)$ is assumed to be a polynomial of finite degree in a single variable. Since we're using a harmonic-oscillator basis to find the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian, a finite-degree polynomial translates to a set of finite powers of the position matrix `xOp`. By increasing the dimension of these matrices while keeping the powers fixed to their finite values, we can achieve convergence of the energy eigenvalues and eigenvectors near the potential minimum.

The larger the matrix dimension, the more of the low-lying eigenvalues will converge to the the true eigenvalues.

First I define position and momentum operators in the basis of harmonic-oscillator eigenfunctions, and a matrix representing the kinetic energy. The dimension of the matrices is `dim`:

**Define basic matrices**

```
xOp[dim_] := 
 SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> #, Band[{2, 1}] -> #}, {#, #} &@dim] &[
  Table[Sqrt[i], {i, dim - 1}]/Sqrt[2]]

eKin[dim_] := 
 1/2 SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> Table[i - 1/2, {i, dim}], 
      Band[{1, 3}] -> #, Band[{3, 1}] -> #}, {#, #} &@dim] &[
  Table[-Sqrt[i (i + 1)/2], {i, dim - 2}]/Sqrt[2]]
```

**Spectrum and eigenfunctions**

This is the heart of the computation.

The function called `spectrum` determines the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a Hamiltonian with the above kinetic energy and a polynomial-type potential energy term. The number of eigenvalues to be returned is given as the first argument, `n`, and their maximum error is given by `tolerance` (the latter can be left out if the default value is sufficient):

```
spectrum[n_, tolerance_: .00001][potential_, var_] /; 
  PolynomialQ[potential, var] := Module[
  {
   x, h, e, v,
   c = CoefficientList[potential, var],
   min = First@Check[
      Minimize[potential, var],
      Print[
       "No absolute potential minimum found. Make sure the leading \
power has a positive coefficient!"];
      Abort[],
      Minimize::natt
      ]
   },
  FixedPoint[
   {#[[1]] + 1, 
     Eigenvalues[
      h = eKin[#[[1]]] + 
        N[Sum[c[[i]] MatrixPower[xOp[#[[1]]], i - 1], {i, 2, 
            Length[c]}] + (c[[1]] - min) IdentityMatrix[#[[
             1]]]], -n]} &, {n + 1, 2 Reverse@Range[n] - 1}, 
   SameTest -> (Max@Abs[#1[[2]] - #2[[2]]] < tolerance &)];
  {e, v} = Reverse /@ Eigensystem[h, -n];
  {e + min, ψe /@ v}
  ]
```

The second set of arguments above (`potential`, `var`) are the potential energy `U(x)` and the name of the position variable - usually it would be `x`.

I had to make a change for compatibility with *Mathematica* **version 10** because it throws an error when you try to apply `MatrixPower` to a numerically singular matrix with power `0`. Position matrices can become numerically singular for large dimension, so I have to treat the zeroth power of `xOp` separately. This wasn't necessary in version 8. Since that term only determines a constant energy offset, it is lumped together with another constant term that I introduce in order to shift the potential minimum to zero (so that the `Eigenvalues` are sorted in ascending order, starting with the ground state - this shift by `min` is undone at the end of the calculation).

**Output results in position basis**

To get the wave function, we implement the sum over basis states to get the wave functions `ψe` (here, `e` doesn't have anything to do with parity - the method works **independently of parity symmetry**). The output format is defined below to yield a shortened representation that doesn't spit out the entire list of coefficients, only listing their number.

```
Format[ψe[l_List]] := ψe[
  Row[{"\[LeftSkeleton]", Length[l], "\[RightSkeleton]"}]]
ψe[l_List][x_] := 1/(Pi^(1/4))Exp[-x^2/ 2] l.(1/Sqrt[2^# #!] HermiteH[#, x] &[Range[Length[l]] - 1])

plotSpectrum[data_, potential_, {var_, min_, max_}] :=
 Show[
  Apply[
    Plot[
      Evaluate[#1 + (Last[#1] - First[#1])/(2 + Length[#1])/
          2 Through[#2[var]]], {var, min, max},
      Prolog -> {Gray, Map[Line[{{min, #}, {max, #}}] &, #1]},
      Frame -> True
      ] &,
    data
    ],
  Plot[potential, {var, min, max}]
  ]
```

**Examples**

Check that we get the correct numerical eigenvalues for the harmonic oscillator potential $U(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^2$ in dimensionless units:

```
spectrum[10][1/2 x^2, x]
```

> {{0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5}, 
>   {ψe[<<15>>], ψe[<<15>>], ψe[<<15>>], ψe[<<15>>], 
>   ψe[<<15>>], ψe[<<15>>], ψe[<<15>>], ψe[<<15>>],
>   ψe[<<15>>], ψe[<<15>>]}}

The first list contains the eigenvalues, the second list has the eigenfunctions in shortened form, ready to be plotted. Note from the short forms that that the number of coefficients used in `ψe` is 15 here, even though I specified that I want to find only `10` eigenvalues in spectrum. This is because these `10` eigenvalues will not be accurate to the given `tolerance` unless the Hamiltonian matrix is diagonalized in a larger Hilbert space of `15` basis functions. Using `FixedPoint`, the procedure iteratively increased the number of basis function until none of the first `10` eigenvalues changed by more than the given tolerance in the next iteration.

**Example 2: quartic oscillator**

Now we'll look at the eigenstates of a quartic potential, shown here:

```
Plot[-3 x^2 + x^4, {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image: quartic]

This is a double-well potential, and the low-lying eigenstates will be localized except for a small tunneling coupling. The potential energy is still a *polynomial* in $x$, so the method should also work here.

```
ψ1 = spectrum[5][-10 x^2 + x^4, x] // Last // Last
```

> ψe[<<72>>]

```
Plot[Evaluate[ψ1[x]], {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image: quarticwave]

If we plot all eigenstates together, the amplitudes are compressed, but you can discern the distinction between even and odd states:

```
With[{v = -10 x^2 + x^4, n = 10},
 plotSpectrum[
  spectrum[n][v, x], v, {x, -4, 4}]
 ]
```

[image: quarticWaves2]

As you can see in the quartic-oscillator example, the number of basis states (`72`) is larger for more complicated potentials. But for the harmonic oscillator test case, it's no problem to get very high accuracy for highly excited levels:

```
First[spectrum[100][1/2 x^2, x]]
```

> {0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5, 15.5, 16.5, 17.5, 18.5, 19.5, 20.5, 21.5, 22.5, 23.5, 24.5, 25.5, 26.5, 27.5, 28.5, 29.5, 30.5, 31.5, 32.5, 33.5, 34.5, 35.5, 36.5, 37.5, 38.5, 39.5, 40.5, 41.5, 42.5, 43.5, 44.5, 45.5, 46.5, 47.5, 48.5, 49.5, 50.5, 51.5, 52.5, 53.5, 54.5, 55.5, 56.5, 57.5, 58.5, 59.5, 60.5, 61.5, 62.5, 63.5, 64.5, 65.5, 66.5, 67.5, 68.5, 69.5, 70.5, 71.5, 72.5, 73.5, 74.5, 75.5, 76.5, 77.5, 78.5, 79.5, 80.5, 81.5, 82.5, 83.5, 84.5, 85.5, 86.5, 87.5, 88.5, 89.5, 90.5, 91.5, 92.5, 93.5, 94.5, 95.5, 96.5, 97.5, 98.5, 99.5}

Comment: That's really helpful! Thanks a lot! But actually my potential is something like (-1 + Tanh[x]) (1 + Tanh[x]), which is not a polynomial, do you have any idea of dealing with this potential? I tried to Fit a polynomial to this potential, but it takes up to x's 30th order to get a reasonable expansion, and that high order makes this method really difficult to converge.

Comment: That potential is very different from the example in your question: it has a bound and a continuous part of the spectrum. You can't hope to use this method for the positive-energy (unbounded) states of your potential. But it should work fine at energies sufficiently far away from the "ionization threshold". The same distinction between the two parts of your spectrum has to be made with any other method, too.

Comment: Yes, I only interested in the bound states. But how should I deal with the Tanh term? Should I just expand it into polynomials or there are other ways to take the Tanh of a matrix ?

Comment: It should be possible to modify the function `spectrum` so that it would allow you to input the potential using matrix notation such as `MatrixPower[x]` and `MatrixExp[x]`. Then you can also treat your exact shape, which simplifies to `MatrixExp` expressions. I'll see if I can do that tomorrow... but the technique has its limitations, and different basis functions may work better. As another alternative for bound state problems, you could also spatially discretize the equation.

Comment: This is very useful. Might I ask here if this method also works if the potential is a piecewise polynomial (say $p_1$ for negative $x$ and $p_2$ for positive $x$)? What about if we have an operator on a halfline? Is it possible to make it work? I could ask a new question, if that is the right way to go.

Comment: @mickep Since we're converting the x operator to matrix form directly, we lose the natural order of the real numbers that allows us to distinguish x<0 from x>0. So I don't see any obvious way to make this work for piecewise polynomials. If you have Dirichlet or Neumann boundary conditions at x=0, that can be enforced by picking the even or odd eigenfunctions of an extended potential symmetric about x=0. But of course then your potential can have only even powers of x.

Comment: I also implemented the code in Korsch and Glück —which I set as an exam question for my undergraduate students (including fixing the issues with some of the plots in that paper) almost 20 years ago. I recently posted my Notebook to the Wolfram Community: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2340693

Comment: @TheDoctor You may be interested to see this more recent reply to a comment, where Korsch et al. show some nice generalizations: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6404/abc139

Comment: @Jens: Amusingly I had recently applied the Korsch and Glück approach to non-Hermitian (PT-Symmetric) Hamiltonians—and it worked very well.

Answer (score 15):

If the potential is $(\tanh (x)+1) (\tanh (x)-1)$ you can obtain the analytic solution using Mathematica as follows:

[I have omitted some of the detail - e.g. the asymptotic expansions - because the details are analogous to the simple harmonic oscillator case in my previous answer (see above).]

Define the potential.

```
u[x_] = (1 + Tanh[x]) (-1 + Tanh[x])
```

Define the differential equation.

```
diffeq = -(1/2) \[Psi]''[x] + u[x] \[Psi][x] == e \[Psi][x]
```

Solve the differential equation.

```
soln = DSolve[diffeq, \[Psi], x][[1, 1]] // Simplify

(* \[Psi] -> Function[{x}, 
  C[1] LegendreP[1, I Sqrt[2] Sqrt[e], Tanh[x]] + 
  C[2] LegendreQ[1, I Sqrt[2] Sqrt[e], Tanh[x]]] *)
```

Verify this solution.

```
diffeq /. soln // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

[This is where I have omitted the asymptotic expansion details.] The `LegendreQ` piece diverges as $x \longrightarrow \infty$, so use `C[2] -> 0` to suppress it. The `LegendreP` piece diverges as $x \longrightarrow -\infty$ with one exception when `e -> -(1/2)`.

So the bound state solution is

```
\[Psi][x] /. soln /. {C[2] -> 0, e -> -(1/2)}

(* 1/2 C[1] Sqrt[1 - Tanh[x]^2] *)
```

Here is a `Manipulate` that illustrates how the solution of the differential equation depends on the energy.

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[LegendreP[1, I Sqrt[2] Sqrt[e], Tanh[x]] // Chop, {x, -5, 5}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "\[Psi]"}], {{e, -1/2, "e"}, -1, 0}]
```

Comment: That's surprising! I never thought this potential could be solved analytically. Thanks so much. Actually, in my other problem I have a slightly different potential `(1 + Tanh[x+1]) (-1 + Tanh[x-1])` do you know whether that potential can be analytically solved as well?

Comment: Mathematica can't solve it analytically, and I can't think of any transformation that might simplify the problem.

Answer (score 15):

As Jens mentioned, the spatially discretize the equation is another alternative for bound state problem. Here is my very simple implementation of this approach. The basic idea is express the equation on a grid. The differentials can be expressed as finite differences. For example, the second order derivative can be expressed as

$$
\frac{d^2\psi}{d x^2}\approx \frac{\psi(x+\Delta x)+\psi(x-\Delta x)-2\psi(x)}{{\Delta x}^2}
$$

So the $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ operator can be expressed as a tridiagonal matrix(zero boundary condition)

$$
\left[ \begin{matrix}
-2 & 1 & & 0\\
1 & \ddots & \ddots & \\
& \ddots & \ddots & 1 \\
0 & & 1 & -2 \end{matrix} \right]
$$

and potential operator is an diagonal matrix

$$
\left[ \begin{matrix}
V(x_1) &  & & 0\\
 & \ddots & & \\
& & \ddots &  \\
0 & &  & V(x_N) \end{matrix} \right]
$$

so the equation in matrix form is

$$
\left[ \begin{matrix}
2a_0+V(x_1) & -a_0 & & 0\\
-a_0 & \ddots & \ddots & \\
& \ddots & \ddots & -a_0 \\
0 & & -a_0 & 2a_0+V(x_N) \end{matrix} \right]
\cdot
\left[\begin{matrix}
\Psi_1\\
\vdots\\
\vdots\\
\Psi_N
\end{matrix}\right]
=
E
\left[\begin{matrix}
\Psi_1\\
\vdots\\
\vdots\\
\Psi_N
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

where $a_0=\frac{\hbar^2}{2m(\Delta x)^2}$.

Diagonalize the hamiltonian will give the eigen-states.

**Code**

```
TISE1D[U_Function, {xmin_, xmax_}, N0Grid_: 101, 
  BoundaryCondition_String: "zero"] := Module[
  {Δx = (xmax - xmin)/(N0Grid - 1), Hmtx, Tmtx, Vmtx},

  Tmtx = -(1/(2 (Δx)^2))
      SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> -2, {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] == 1 -> 
       1}, {N0Grid, N0Grid}];
  Vmtx = DiagonalMatrix[U /@ Range[xmin, xmax, Δx]];
  Hmtx = Tmtx + Vmtx;
  If[BoundaryCondition == "periodic",
   Hmtx[[1, -1]] = Hmtx[[-1, 1]] = -(1/(2 (Δx)^2));
   ];
  Sort[Transpose@Eigensystem[Hmtx], (#1[[1]] < #2[[1]]) &]

  ]
```

**Examples**

1.Harmonic oscillator

```
V1[x_] = 1/2. x^2;

Transpose[TISE1D[Function[{x}, V1[x]], {-10, 10}, 400]][[1, 1 ;; 4]]
(*{0.499921,1.49961,2.49898,3.49804}*)

ListPlot[TISE1D[Function[{x}, V1[x]], {-10, 10}, 400][[1 ;; 4, 2]], 
 Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, All}, DataRange -> {-10, 10}, 
 Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

2.Reflectionless potential

```
V2[x_] = With[{\[HBar] = 1, m = 1, a = 1.4}, -((\[HBar]^2 a^2)/m) Sech[a x]^2];
```

For this potential the analytical bound state wave function is $\psi(x)=A*sech(a x)$
 and the ground state energy is $E_0=-\frac{a^2 \hbar ^2}{2 m}$.

```
grd = TISE1D[Function[{x}, V2[x]], {-10, 10}][[1, 2]];
With[{a = 1.4}, {TISE1D[Function[{x}, V2[x]], {-10, 10}, 200][[1, 1]], -1.4^2/2}]
(*{-0.980757,-0.98}*)

Show[ListPlot[Abs[grd]^2, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
  DataRange -> {-10, 10}], 
 Plot[Max[Abs[grd]^2]*Sech[1.4 x]^2, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

3.potential $V(x)=-\frac{b \hbar ^2}{m}\text{sech}^2(a x)$.

```
V3[x_] = With[{\[HBar] = 1, m = 1, a0 = 10., a = 0.81, b = 1.94}, -((\[HBar]^2 b)/m) Sech[a x]^2];

bdE = Select[Transpose[TISE1D[Function[{x}, V3[x]], {-10, 10}, 200]][[1]]*27.211, # < 0 &]
(*{-35.1018, -8.64135}*)

ListPlot[TISE1D[Function[{x}, V2[x]], {-10, 10}, 200][[1 ;; 2, 2]], 
 PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, DataRange -> {-10, 10}, 
 Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

As in version 10.2, there is the [`NDEigensystem`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDEigensystem.html) can be used to calculate the eigenstates and eigenvalues of a differential operator.

For example in the harmonic potential case, the even and odd eigen functions can be calculated using Neumann and Dirichlet boundary condition respectively:

```
{egnVal1, egnVec1} = 
  NDEigensystem[{-1/2 Laplacian[u[x], {x}] + 1/2 x^2 u[x]}, 
   u[x], {x, 0, 10}, 2];

{egnVal2, egnVec2} = 
  NDEigensystem[{-1/2 Laplacian[u[x], {x}] + 1/2 x^2 u[x], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, True]}, u[x], {x, 0, 10}, 2];
```

And the eigenenergies are:

```
egnVal = Riffle[egnVal1, egnVal2]
(* {0.500079, 1.50054, 2.5019, 3.5047} *)
```

And the eigenstates are:

```
egnVec = Riffle[egnVec1, egnVec2];  
Plot[Evaluate[egnVec], {x, 0, 6}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

which gives the correct wave functions apart from the arbitrary phases.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a symbolic solution of your eigenvalue problem.

Define the differential equation (setting $\hbar = \omega = m_0 = 1$).

```
diffeq = -(1/2) ψ''[x] + 1/2 x^2 ψ[x] == e ψ[x]
```

Symbolically solve the differential equation.

```
soln = DSolve[diffeq, ψ, x][[1, 1]]

(* ψ -> Function[{x}, 
   C[2] ParabolicCylinderD[1/2 (-1 - 2 e), I Sqrt[2] x] + 
   C[1] ParabolicCylinderD[1/2 (-1 + 2 e), Sqrt[2] x]] *)
```

Inspect the $x \longrightarrow +\infty$ limit by series expanding there:

```
ψ[x] /. soln // Series[#, {x, ∞, 1}] & // Simplify // 
   Normal // Collect[#, E^(x^2/2), Simplify] &

(* 2^(-(1/4) + e/2) E^(-(x^2/2)) Sqrt[1/x] x^
   e C[1] + (1 - I) 2^(-(3/4) - e/2) E^(x^2/2) Sqrt[1/x]
   x^-e C[2] (Cos[(e π)/2] - I Sin[(e π)/2]) *)
```

We need `C[2]->0` in order to suppress the divergent exponential term.

Now inspect the $x \longrightarrow -\infty$ limit by series expanding there:

```
ψ[x] /. soln /. {C[2] -> 0} // 
   Series[#, {x, -∞, 1}] & // Simplify // Normal // Expand

(* -2^(-(1/4) + e/2) E^(2 I e π - x^2/2) (1/x)^(1/2 - e) C[1]
   - (I 2^(1/4 - e/2) E^(-I e π + x^2/2) Sqrt[π] (1/x)^(1/2 + e)
   C[1])/Gamma[1/2 - e] *)
```

We need `e -> n + 1/2` (where `n` is a non-negative integer) to make the `1/Gamma[1/2 - e]` suppress the divergent exponential term. This makes use of the fact that $\Gamma(x)$ is singular for $x = 0,-1,-2,-3,\cdots$.

Gathering it all together gives the solution

```
ψ[x] /. soln /. {C[2] -> 0, e -> n + 1/2}

(* C[1] ParabolicCylinderD[1/2 (-1 + 2 (1/2 + n)), Sqrt[2] x] *)
```

which can be normalised by choosing `C[1]` appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, but my real problem is the potential (1+Tanh[x])(-1+Tanh[x]), I was using the harmonic potential just to illustrate the parametric method, since the harmonic potential is a text book example that can be solved analytically, we can compare the solution.