# Computing Hypergeometric Funtion of Matrix Argument

Tags: special-functions

I'm new to Mathematica and unsure of how to compute functions or set up definitions.

I'd like to do some computations with the $_1F_1$ hypergeometric function of matrix argument as in the [*Koev and Edelman*](http://math.mit.edu/~plamen/files/hyper.pdf) paper. That paper only includes code for MATLAB, but I don't have access to it so I was hoping to do my computations with Mathematica (I saw another [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58298/hypergeometric-function-with-a-matrix-argument) which had some code for this function).

Would somebody please walk me through the process of defining and computing values of this function.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you give an example problem please? Intuitively I'd suggest to diagonalize the matrix, calculate the hypergeometric function on the diagonal elements, and then transform back, in the same way that matrix exponentials are computed.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. Do not expect people to follow your links and download files, explain what you need directly.

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) because you have not explained what you need in enough detail. To avoid or revert the Hold you can [edit] your question to [improve it](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) and make it specific, well-structured and easy to understand. Please don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your questions are and will be most welcomed. Learn about [good questions here](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3).

Comment: Have you tried [MatrixFunction](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixFunction.html)? For example, `MatrixFunction[Hypergeometric1F1[0.1, 0.3, #] &, A]` to calculate the matrix hypergeometric of a matrix `A`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58298/hypergeometric-function-with-a-matrix-argument -- seems that the accepted answer does just what you ask, no?

Comment: @MichaelE2 When the answer was accepted, `MatrixFunction` didn't exist yet. But there's an answer pointing to it at the end of your linked question.

Comment: @Roman Are you saying this should be closed as found in the docs, as a duplicate, or something else?

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes I think so.