# Numerical solution of Schrödinger equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I want to solve the following differential equation numerically. The geometry of the problem is as shown below. Electron 1 is located on the inner ring of radius $R_1$ and electron 2 is located on the outer ring of radius $R_2$ and are vertically separated by a distance $d$ given by 
[image: diagram]

$d^2(\phi_1,\phi_2;R_1,R_2,\alpha)=[R_2 \cos \phi_2-R_1 \cos \phi_1]^2+[R_2 \cos \alpha-R_2+R_2 \cos\alpha \sin\phi_2-R_1 \sin \phi_1]^2+R_2^2 \sin^2 \alpha [1+\sin \phi_2]^2$

```
1/Subscript[R, 1]^2 D[ψ[Subscript[ϕ, 1], Subscript[ϕ,2]], {Subscript[ϕ, 1], 2}] - 
  1/Subscript[R, 2]^2 D[ψ[Subscript[ϕ, 1], Subscript[ϕ,2]], {Subscript[ϕ, 2], 2}] + 
    1/d ψ[Subscript[ϕ, 1], Subscript[ϕ, 2]] = 
  e ψ[Subscript[ϕ, 1], Subscript[ϕ, 2]]
```

where $\phi_i\in[0,2\pi)$ with periodic boundary conditions $\Psi(0,\phi_2)=\Psi(2\pi,\phi_2)$,$\Psi(\phi_1,0)=\Psi(\phi_1,2\pi)$

Comment: ...and you've already looked at the docs for `NDSolve[]`?

Comment: @J.M I'm trying it!

Comment: You are trying to solve the time-independent Schrodinger equation and it is an eigenvalue problem. One way is to write the equation in the difference form and diagonalize the Hamiltonian. Here is an example for 1D version: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32293/1364 I think NDSolve maybe more useful for time-dependent Schrodinger equation, which is a PDE problem.

Comment: Please edit your question to specify `d`.  If you wish a numerical solution, also specify `R1` and `R2`.  Finally, please provide your equation in Mathematica format as well.  Because this appears to be an eigenvalue problem, there is no need to specify the normalization of Psi.  Thanks.

Comment: You may want to look at `NDEigensystem` which can solve eigensystem numerically for a differential operator. I have added a 1D example in the same link.

Comment: Your kinetic energy term is probably wrong (not positive definite). You're also using notation like `E` and `=` that isn't syntactically correct.

Comment: @Jens, I simply write the equation.

Comment: @Jens, The electronic Hamiltonian of the system is H=T+u^-1 where T= T1 + T2

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified the region of interest. But suppose it is that region between the two rings (say of radius 3 & 5 ), with appropriate units taken into account, we examine the first eigenfunction using

```
 {vals, funs} =      NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0., x == 0]}, u[x, y], 
  Element[{x, y}, RegionSymmetricDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 5], 
         Disk[{0, 0}, 3]]], 1]



 Plot3D[funs, Element[{x, y}, RegionSymmetricDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 5], 
        Disk[{0, 0}, 3]]], PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> vals, 
    PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

Visualize  the eigenfunction below. If this is not what you are after, then amend the first part using `{x, y} \[Element] Disk[]`
[image]

Comment: I am using V8 when I try to run it shows me error message.

Comment: No error for 10.3, probably the newer version has upgraded features

Comment: I got the result {{0.0427379}, {InterpolatingFunction[{{-5., 5.}, {-5., 5.}}, <>][x,y]}} but takes too much time for the plot.

Comment: That's gd. Computation time is a bit long here as well.

Comment: It's strange I couldn't see the plot you posted, still running.

Comment: Generating the plot was no problem. My code is just a rough guess based on your question, is this what you are after?

Comment: U using version 10.3?

Comment: Yes, I'm using 10.3

Comment: there's a considerable difference the first eigenfunction with this paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.0649

Comment: Not sure how to respond......as my naïve code differs  hugely from the problem specified  in the paper....my response is only a guess