# ParametricNDSolveValue for ODE with boundary at infinity

Tags: differential-equations, physics, parametric-functions, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I'm trying solve the Schrödinger equation for a given potential using the function ParametricNDSolveValue following the the first method of the post:

[Find eigen energies of time-independent Schrödinger equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32293/find-eigen-energies-of-time-independent-schr%C3%B6dinger-equation)

It works fine, but it bothers me that we have to impose the somewhat artificial boundary condition ψ[1]==1 instead of the real condition ψ[Infinity]==0.

I've tried two different ideas to get around this:

a. Imposing the condition ψ[100]==10^-5 or similar values, the problem with this is that afterwards Findroot doesn't return the right values of the energy (I tested with the known results. of the harmonic oscillator). Oddly, if I use ψ[3]==0.01 I get better results than with ψ[3]==0.0001 or ψ[10]==0.0001 and definitely than with ψ[100]==10^-5 (?!)

b. Using ParametricNDSolveValue with two parameters, one for the Energy and one for the the boundary conditions, ie. ψ[100]==k, and the using Findroot for the energy making k=0, but again, results are wrong.

So my questions are:

1. Why do I get better results using the boundary condition ψ[3]==0.01 than using ψ[3]==0.0001 or ψ[10]==0.0001 when the latest are closer to the real boundary condition?
2. Is there a way of using the fonction ParametricNDSolveValue when boundaries are infinity or close enough?

Comment: You should post your code so we know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Why do I get better results using the boundary condition ψ[3]==0.01

`E^(-(x)^2/2)*(1/Pi)^(1/4) /. x -> 3 // N` gives `0.00834425`, so to answer your question: ψ[3]==0.01 gives a better result because it is a better approximation, for the fundamental state at least. And ψ[3]==0.008 would be even better!

But you should be aware that this will not be a good approximation for higher energy states.

2. Is there a way of using the fonction ParametricNDSolveValue when boundaries are infinity or close enough?

**Since computers dont have infinite memory** we cant solve DE over infinitely large regions. We have to truncate our region of intrest at some point.

I found that

```
U[x_] := 1/2  x^2;
L = 6;
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{-1/2 \[Psi]''[x] + U[x] \[Psi][x] == 
     Ei \[Psi][x], \[Psi][L] == 0, \[Psi][0] == 
     1}, \[Psi], {x, -L, L}, {Ei}];

Plot[Evaluate@pfun[.5][x], {x, -3, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {All, {-2, 2}}]

Plot[Evaluate@pfun[2.5][x], {x, -3, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {All, {-2, 2}}]
```

works well for even half energies (I tried up to 6.5). If you want more excited states you might need to truncate over a larger area (bigger L), but that will make the computation take more time.

Also notice the initial condition  `\[Psi][0] == 1`, it was necessary to keep the final result from being the trivial one: `\[Psi][x] == 0`, for odd solutions you will have to change it to `\[Psi]'[0] == 1`. Both artificial conditions might generate unnormalized solutions.