# Stationary 1-D Schrodinger equation for calculating energy of a -CH3 group quantum rotor in a metal organic framework

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I am trying to calculate the energy of a quantum mechanical rotor by plugging a potential function predicted from DFT calculations in this paper: [DOI:10.1039/C8CC02650E](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2018/cc/c8cc02650e#!divAbstract)

The potential can be approximated by:

```
U[x_] := (-V Sin[3 x ]^4 + V) Cos[3 x ]^2 + (V/2 Cos[6 x ] + V/2) Sin[3 x ]^2;
```

Where `V` is the height of the potential, and `x` is the angle of rotation of the H3 group of atoms.

It is also reported that for this -CH3 the Schrodinger equation can be written simply as:

$\qquad -B\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}+U(x)~\psi=Ei~\psi$

where $B = 0.665 meV$

I have been trying to use the method published here:

$\qquad$ [Find eigen energies of time-independent Schrödinger equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32293/60024)

I modified the potential and pfun1, as well as the limits on x. But I think that I should change the boundary conditions on $\psi$?

```
V = 13.17;
U[x_] := (-V Sin[3 x ]^4 + V)*Cos[3 x ]^2 + (V/2 Cos[6 x ] + V/2)*
Sin[3 x ]^2;

pfun1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{-B ψ''[x] + U[x] ψ[x] == 
Ei ψ[x], ψ[0.] == 0., ψ[1.] == 
1.}, ψ, {x, -2 π, 2 π}, {Ei}]
```

I'm also not sure about the value of `x` to supply to `FindRoot`.

```
Plot[pfun1[Ei][?], {Ei, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> Medium]
val1 = Map[FindRoot[pfun1[Ei][?], {Ei, 0}] &, {1, 2, 3}]
```

Comment: You'll want to use something like `{eV, eF} = 
 NDEigensystem[{-B \[Psi]''[x] + 
    U[x] \[Psi][x], \[Psi][0] == \[Psi][2 \[Pi]]}, \[Psi], {x, 0, 
   2 \[Pi]}, 3]` where the last number is the number of eigenvalues `eV` and eigenfunctions `eF` you wish to calculate. The point is that the variable `x` is an angle and therefore you need periodic boundary conditions at `x = 0, 2 Pi`. The answer you were using was written before the new `NDEigensystem` had been introduced...

Comment: Perhaps this can come handy: [Find the Spectrum of a Schrödinger Operator](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/differential-eigensystems/find-the-spectrum-of-a-schrdinger-operator.html)

Comment: Thank you @Jens - most useful! For some reason it refuses to plot the eigenfunctions using Plot - just gives a blank graph.

Comment: Thanks @VitaliyKaurov - very nice example indeed!